# How to rearrange data from multiple columns to one column in excel

Tags: vba, excel

My data looks like this

```
2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 
A     B     G   H    J
J     G     R   J    K
```

I want it to look like this

```
2010  A
2011  B
2012  G
2013  H
2014  J
2010  J
2011  G
2012  R
2013  J 
2014  K
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal  You will need to add a garbage column to the left of your data that you delete after ward.

Comment: Do you really want to do this with VBA?

Answer (score 1):

1) copy row 1 and insert between 2 and 3, you will get:

```
2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 
  A     B     G   H    J
2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 
  J     G     R   J    K
```

2) copy row 3 & 4 and paste behind data in line 1/2, you will get:

```
2010 2011 2012 2013 2014  2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 
  A     B     G   H    J    J    G    R    J    K
```

3) copy all data, paste with transponation and you will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array formula](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+array+formula). When `a1:a3` is `2010, A, J`, let's put output at `g:h`.

First, select `g1:g5` and hit `F2` and type `=TRANSPOSE(A1:E1)` and hit `ctrl + shift + enter`. Now `g1:g5` should be `2010, 2011, ..., 2014`.

Select `g6:g10` and hit `F2` and type `=TRANSPOSE(A1:E1)` and hit `ctrl + shift + enter`. Now `g1:g5` should be `2010, 2011, ..., 2014`.

select `h1:h5` and hit `F2` and type `=TRANSPOSE(A2:E2)` and hit `ctrl + shift + enter`. Now `h1:h5` should be `A, B, ..., J`.

Select `h6:h10` and hit `F2` and type `=TRANSPOSE(A3:E3)` and hit `ctrl + shift + enter`. Now `g1:g5` should be `J, G, ..., K`.

[image]